# Using Azure AD to authenticate react application and backend application(python)

Tags: python, reactjs, azure

I am able to authenticate the react app with AAD and I am able to get the access token.

I have the following questions:

1. My backend is in python flask (WEB API's). How do I make sure that every request sent by react app is also authenticated with the same token?
2. Should I register a different application for the backend( python flask) or I can use the client ID of the same frontend application?
3. If I am passing the token in the header while calling every API request from the frontend, how backend will verify is the token is valid? Also, should it verify every API request?

I have seen multiple options like flask-azure-oauth library and some other libraries. For frontend I have tried ADAL and MSAL libraries.

Answer (score 2):

1. In frontend make sure you append the accessToken in you're each HTTP request like, writing a common HTTP module and use it across the react app. And to make sure you're app is authenticated with same token you need to wrap react app with `adal` or `MSAL` or `react-adal`.
2. You have to use the same `client id` which used in react app in you're python backend in-order to verify the token you're sending in the API request.
3. You need to add `before_request` hook in flask and verify the accessToken you receive in the request. [reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55193868/before-action-only-how-to-do-this-in-python-flask)

you can also check [react-adal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-adal) package for AAD authentication.